# iOS App - Device begins to heat up after certain interval of time

Tags: ios, webrtc, arkit, realitykit, overheating

We have used Webrtc & ARKit to implement video communication in our iOS app. Using RTCVideoCapturer, we send the customized frame to the WebRTC. While sending the frame via WebRTC, we first capture a screenshot of the View, then get the CgImage and generate the pixel buffer.

This works perfectly, but after certain interval of time the device starts to heat up. An increase in CPU usage causes a heating problem.

What modifications can be made to reduce CPU usage?

[CPU Utilization & Thermal State Changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kgzr.png)